# BDD-JAVA- Is it possible to generate cucumber html reports with only scenario titles with out steps

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am currently using an HTML formatter to generate the Cucumber HTML report. The report is pretty, but I want the reports to be generated with all scenarios only with the title so that my report is not huge and easy to know which scenarios failed.

To clarify more, when cucumber HTML report is generated. I am seeing headers are divided into Steps (Passed, Failed, Skipped, Pending, Undefined), Scenarios(Passed, Failed, Skipped, Pending, Undefined), Feature. I just wanted to customize and print only Scenarios and remove steps section

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WspSl.png)

public class HtmlFormatter extends CucumberJSONFormatter {
    private static final String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS z";

```
public HtmlFormatter(Appendable out) {
    super(out);
}

@Override
public void done() {
    super.done();

    final List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    final ConfigReader configReader = new ConfigReader();
    final File reportOutputDirectory = new File("reports/html");
    final int numThreads = Integer.valueOf(configReader.getProperty("maxThreads", "4"));

    //in case running from single feature file
    if (Main.isFeatureFileExecution()) {
        final String singleFeatureFileExecutionReportPath = "reports/"+configReader.getProperty( "repo","RepoNameNotFound" ) +"/json/report.json";
        if (new File(singleFeatureFileExecutionReportPath).exists()) {
            jsonFiles.add(singleFeatureFileExecutionReportPath);
        }
    } 

    String projectName = “X”;
    boolean runWithJenkins = true;
    boolean parallelTesting = true;

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, projectName);
    configuration.setParallelTesting(parallelTesting);
    configuration.setRunWithJenkins(runWithJenkins);

    if (!jsonFiles.isEmpty()) {
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
        Reportable result = reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code, and an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The code belongs in your question, not in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Write your own custom reporter based on the HTML reporter. As you are just trying to remove a small bit of functionality from the reporter this shouldn't be to difficult. Then use your reporter when running cucumber.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @diabolist from the above question code do you have any suggestions that I can include or delete to accomplish my req?

Comment: No, sorry I've never messed around with reporters. You could try the Cucumber community on slack.